# Why is the "file" concept in standard hosted C so generic?

Tags: c, file, standards

Every hosted implementation that I know of has some way of representing the following concepts. Are there implementations in use that don't? If not, why doesn't C require standard APIs for them so that more portable code can be used?

- Creating a directory
- Creating a file or directory in a directory, with some notion of a directory separator character
- Absolute paths
- Relative paths
- Current working directory
- Home directory
- Deleting an empty directory
- Some form of file metadata/attributes
- File moving (can be implemented as copy + remove, but usually the OS has a more efficient/atomic way e.g. inodes)
- A maximum file name length
- Filenames that consist solely of ASCII alphabetical characters (with possible case insensitivity)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVS doesn't have directories per-se, for example. So a bunch of your stuff in that list doesn't map properly.

Comment: Hmm...POSIX and SUS *are* a standardized API that support those parts of that list that make sense in unix. They are not part of the language, because they *shouldn't* be part of a systems language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Creating a directory

My understanding (I've never used them) is that IBM mini (ex OS 400, I don't remember their current name) and mainframes (I think their current name is zSeries) have a different way enough of organizing their files that it wouldn't map well on your (or mine) notion of directory.

> - Creating a file or directory in a directory, with some notion of a directory separator character

VMS file names are structured like  `D:[A.B.C]name.ext;ver`

> - File moving (can be implemented as copy + remove, but usually the OS has a more efficient/atomic way e.g. inodes)

rename is present in C since C90.

> - A maximum file name length

Unix doesn't have it for some time (well, it is per file system and some have it so high that it doesn't make sense to consider there is one).

> - Filenames that consist solely of ASCII alphabetical characters (with possible case insensitivity)

I doubt very much that IBM mainframe are using ASCII for file name while they are using EBCDIC for everything.

Comment: IBM mainframes are POSIX compliant to the best of my knowledge. But they did use entirely different file structure (all these ISAMs and such) until not so long ago. ASCII vs EBCDIC also doesn't have much to do with C, its just poor choice of words of the OP. All these services can be provided by any OS (and usually are), its just that limiting the programming language to POSIX OS's is not necessarily a good thing for a language such as C.

Comment: @littleadv, if they may have a POSIX compliance layer in order to be able to submit in procurements where POSIX compliance is required, I doubt that they are often operated in practice using that layer. (Windows has at least 3 such layers, and I seem to recall that VMS has also one).

Comment: GNU HURD has no maximum file name length at all - and note that even POSIX doesn't specify a file moving primitive (other than `rename()` which doesn't have to work across mountpoints).

Comment: Yes, but the point is that none of the reasons you mentioned is the reason for the POSIX functions not to be included in the C standard. C++ and Java can be used for mainframe programming as well, yet they have (some or all of) these functionalities.

Comment: @littleadv, the reason for which there is nothing in the standard is that nobody took the pain to propose something and convince the other members that it was worth the pain.  C++ has nothing more than C in that respect (but I'm aware of propositions for C++, none for C).  And Java practice is more open to thick interface layer than C++, and even more so, than C.  And for something which has user interface aspect, and file name and directory structure have, I prefer an interface which allows user to use the system conventions instead of imported one which miss concepts.

Comment: I've worked on a couple of systems that didn't have hierarchical directory structures (HP MPE and an old Encore mini).  MPE had a POSIX shell, but the native environment organized files by group and account, and that was it.

Comment: @littleadv - IBM mainframes are Posix compliant because they can run Linux. Most of the software run under z/OS which doesn't have directories in the file structure.

Answer (score 3):

Because when C was developed, the concept of directories, or file systems in general, wasn't as wide-spread as it is now. How would you implement all that you describe on a system that doesn't have a file system, and still be C-compatible? You can't.

C file is a stream, which can be also a tape in a tape recorder. Pretty common then. Directories were shelves in cabinets. Go delete these in your C code...

Comment: Were any such systems in use on 12/19/2011, when C11 was published? What about on 12/01/1999, when C99 was published? It's a serious question, I'm prepared for either answer.

Comment: @SheaLevy There still are systems like that. Many embedded systems don't even have an OS kernel, just a simple C-coded monolithic application that runs them.

Comment: Which currently in-use system that is a _hosted_ C implementation doesn't have these concepts?

Comment: @SheaLevy I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "hosted" C implementation, but the question should be "whether we can decide that **any** system **must** have these concepts". The C standard committee decided that they're not in a position for such a claim. Are you?

Comment: See section 1.7 of http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt for what I mean by "hosted", to my knowledge most embedded systems with no OS are freestanding implementations, not hosted ones.

Comment: @SheaLevy thanks for the clarification, irrelevant as it may be.

Comment: As for "am I in the position"? I'm not an expert in the field of existing C implementations, this is why I'm asking the question: Which current system does not have these concepts? Alternatively, what reason would a modern new but not-yet-existent implementation have for not having these concepts?

Comment: @SheaLevy well, you can ask another question to cover these issues. I think I answered your question sufficiently, and anyway I voted to close it as I knew it would lead to this discussion, and nothing anyone can say here will satisfy you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6276/discussion-between-shea-levy-and-littleadv)

Comment: @SheaLevy: as I pointed out below your question, some mainframe-type systems have radically different storage concepts from what you're used. As for idle speculation about the future: pointless. At some point in time, the wheel didn't exist.

Comment: @littleadv: The distinction between freestanding and hosted implementations is important, because this distinction is drawn by the standard and different requirements are attached to each category of implementation.